# Can't write the results of a list into a json or txt file

Tags: r

I some data in an unlisted object and I want to write them to a file json or txt.

I type this:

```
write(unlist, "test.json")
```

but it stacks with this reported problem:

```
Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'
```

What should I check to my data in order to fix this problem?

Comment: What does `str(unlist)` tell you?

Comment: @alexforrence please find here the result of str(unlist) http://jpst.it/yk8a

Comment: Sorry, that might have been misleading. More directly, `typeof(unlist)`.

Comment: @alexforrence typing the command you mention it prints this "list"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I write things to JSON. Hope it helps...

```
library("RJSONIO")
mylist <- list(a=1:5, b=letters, c="character string here")
mylist_json <- toJSON(mylist)
cat(mylist_json, file="~/Desktop/tmp.json")
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I tried the cat(..) but still I can't write the data to a json file it prints Error in cat(list(...), file, sep, fill, labels, append) : 
  argument 1 (type 'list') cannot be handled by 'cat'

Comment: You can't write a list... you need to convert it to JSON first. See my code above...